# $f\geq 0$ Prove that $f$ is integrable on $(E,\mu)$ iff $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n\mu(E_n) < \infty$ where..

Tags: calculus, analysis, measure-theory

$f\geq 0$ Prove that $f$ is integrable on $(E,\mu)$ iff $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n\mu(E_n) < \infty$$ where $E_n=\{x \in E | n \leq f(x) <n+1\}$

If there is need for a better clarification as to what $E$ is , somewhere above the page it says on another assignment that $E= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ In the same assignment it says that $E$ is non-measurable. That makes no sense to me.

Comment: You need to assume $f$ is measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose we multiply the $n$th term in the sum by $(n+1)/n?$

Added later: Note that $\int_X f \, d\mu = \sum_n \int_{E_n} f\, d\mu .$ Therefore

$$\sum_n n\mu(E_n) \le \int_X f \, d\mu \le \sum_n (n+1)\mu(E_n).$$

But the terms in the second sum are $(n+1)/n$ times the terms in the first sum. Since $(n+1)/n \to 1,$ these sums converge or diverge together. The result follows from this.

Comment: Can you clarify on this?

Comment: I added to my answer.

Comment: Can you add more detail behind the deductions realated to  "Therefore"... (this inequality). I might be having difficulties with this because this is the first type of question I am doing from this area.

Comment: On $E_n,$ $n\le f <n+1,$ so $\int_{E_n}n\,d\mu \le \int_{E_n}f\,d\mu \le \int_{E_n}(n+1)\,d\mu.$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Letting $1_{A}$ be the indicator function on $A$, then you have the following inequalities:
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n 1_{E_n}(x) \leq f(x) \leq \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) 1_{E_n}(x) 
$$
for every $x \in \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} E_n$.